# How can I best model this as a Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am creating a database for a website. It should contain information about a company, information about cases that companies create and finally reports that companies make for the cases.

I have the following objects:

- Companies
- Cases
- Reports

For these objects I have the following requirements:

- A company has an id which is unique.
- A case has an id. It belongs to a company and it is unique in that context.
- A report has an id. It belongs to a case and it is unique in that context.
- **One** company can have **Many** cases.
- **One** case can have **Many** reports.

I have tried to model this using MySQL Workbench:

[image]

I made a many-to-one identifying relationship between `case` and `company`, because cases uniquely belong to companies. I made a many-to-one relationship between `report` and `case`, because reports uniquely belong to cases.

How can I model this, in a simple way, such that two companies can have a case each with the same id but otherwise different? And furthermore, a single company can't have two cases with the same id.

Comment: hi, i think you dont need the case_company on report table (its redundant information)and case_id on report table dont need to be part of the primary key, same happend in case table with company_id field, dont need to be primary key. hope its helps

Comment: I changed the wording of the problem just now. Are those columns still redundant in light of the new explanation? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.

One, you could have a multiple column primary key. This is essentially the way you have it now.

Two, you could create a surrogate key--a made up value which uniquely identifies each row. Most databases can generate these automatically, starting with 1 and incrementing for each new row. You would then add constraints to enforce your business logic. A surrogate key is nice because it is always simple and if your logic or business rules change then you don't have to completely redesign your table, just change your constraints. The discussion of when you should use a surrogate key and when you should use a natural (already existent data) key is long, but boils down to those two points--if a natural key would be complicated or if business logic is likely to change.

If you switch to a surrogate key, your primary key for case will become a simple integer, the case_company_id column in report would be redundant, and the primary key for report would also only be a simple integer.

Comment: Thanks. After reading this I have decided to go with the surrogate key solution.